# How do you define variables to be used by multiple functions when creating custom libraries in C++

Tags: c++, variables, libraries

I would like some guidance on how to get rid of duplicated variables.

```cpp
    char Temp_File[40] ="/";
    char End_File[8] = ".csv";
    File Parameter_File;
```

I am unsure on where to declare these variables so they can be used by all functions in the library, but not interfere when the library is used by the main program (Not included here).

This is a project on an esp32-C3 chip and I am using the Arduino IDE to program said chip

Here is the .h and .cpp files for my library

Info_Saver.h file

```
#ifndef INFO_SAVER_H
#define INFO_SAVER_H

#include "FS.h"
#include "FFat.h"

namespace Info_Saver{
    class Info_Saver {
        #define FORMAT_FFAT true
        public:
            void Save_Info(char * File_Name, int Value_In);
  
            void Format_Space();
    
            void Delete_Parameter(char * File_Name);
    
            void Read_Parameter(char * File_Name, char * Value_Out);
    
            void List_Dir(const char * Dir_Name, uint8_t levels);
    };
}
#endif
```

Info_Saver.cpp file

```
#include "Info_Saver.h"

void Info_Saver::Info_Saver::Save_Info(char * File_Name, int Value_In) {
    char Temp_File[40] ="/";
    char End_File[8] = ".csv";
    File Parameter_File;

    strcat(Temp_File, File_Name);
    strcat(Temp_File, End_File); 

    //Serial.println(File_Name);
    //Serial.println(Temp_File);
    Parameter_File = FFat.open(Temp_File,FILE_WRITE);
    if(!Parameter_File){
      Serial.println("- failed to open file for writing");
    } else {
      Parameter_File.print(Value_In);
      Parameter_File.print('\n');
      //Serial.print("The value is: ");
      //Serial.println(Value_In);
    }
    Parameter_File.close();
    strcpy(Temp_File, "/");
    return;
}

void Info_Saver::Info_Saver::Format_Space() { 
    if (!FFat.begin()) {
    FFat.format();
    }
    return;
}

void Info_Saver::Info_Saver::Delete_Parameter(char * File_Name) {
    char Temp_File[40] ="/";
    char End_File[8] = ".csv";
    File Parameter_File;

    strcat(Temp_File, File_Name);
    strcat(Temp_File,End_File); 

    //Serial.println(File_Name);
    //Serial.println(Temp_File);
    if(FFat.remove(Temp_File)) {
        Serial.println("- file deleted");    
    } else {
        Serial.println("- delete failed");
    }
    strcpy(Temp_File, "/");
    return;
}

void Info_Saver::Info_Saver::Read_Parameter(char * File_Name, char * Value_Out) {
    char Temp_File[40] ="/";
    char End_File[8] = ".csv";
    File Parameter_File;

    char Temp_Out;
    strcat(Temp_File, File_Name);
    strcat(Temp_File,End_File);

    //Serial.println(File_Name);
    //Serial.println(Temp_File);
    Parameter_File = FFat.open(Temp_File);
    if(!Parameter_File || Parameter_File.isDirectory()) {
        // add || Parameter_File.isDirectory() if there are issues
        Serial.print("- failed to open file for reading");
        Serial.print("\n");
    } else {
        while(Parameter_File.available()) {
            static unsigned int Temp_Int = 0;
            Temp_Out = Parameter_File.read();
            if (Temp_Out != '\n'  && Temp_Int < 7) {
                Value_Out[Temp_Int] = Temp_Out;
                Temp_Int++;
            } else {
                Value_Out[Temp_Int] = '\0';
                Temp_Int = 0;
                break;
            }
        } 
        //Serial.print("The value is: ");
        //Serial.print(Value_Out);
        //Serial.print("\n");
    }
    Parameter_File.close();
    strcpy(Temp_File, "/");
    return;
}

void Info_Saver::Info_Saver::List_Dir(const char * Dir_Name, uint8_t levels) {
    File Root;
    Root = FFat.open(Dir_Name);
    if (!Root) {
        Serial.println("- failed to open directory");
        return;
    } else if (!Root.isDirectory()) {
        Serial.println(" - not a directory");
        return;
    }

    File Temp_Root = Root.openNextFile();
    while(Temp_Root){
        
        if(Temp_Root.isDirectory()){
            Serial.print("  DIR : ");
            Serial.println(Temp_Root.name());
        
            if(levels){
                List_Dir(Temp_Root.path(), levels -1);
            }
        
        } else {
            Serial.print("  FILE: ");
            Serial.print(Temp_Root.name());
            Serial.print("\tSIZE: ");
            Serial.println(Temp_Root.size());
        }
        Temp_Root = Root.openNextFile();
    }
    return;
}
```

I have tried declaring the variables in the .h file, and at the beginning of the .cpp file. I could not get the program to work when the variables were declared in the .h file. This could easily be an issue on how I declared them in the .h file, I just am not sure on how to do it properly.

When I declared the variables at the beginning of the .cpp file, I realized that the variables became global. This in turn wreaked havoc in the main program. Though, it did allow me to use the variables in all the functions.

Comment: The shown code appears to demonstrate your knowledge and awareness of C++ classes, so aren't you asking about and simply describing plain, garden-variety, class members? This is what class members are for: just make them members of the `Info_Saver` class, and move on to the next task.

Comment: Or make them members of their own class, and move the code that initializes them into the class's constructor, with the constructor taking the `File_Name` parameter. Simple. Clean. Straightforward. Nothing more complicated than basic C++ class construction and instantiation.

Comment: But they're not the *same* variables. They're temporary stack variables used by each function. Each function will build them in different ways. The storage for them comes and goes as each function begins and ends. And, most importantly... you can still recurse through those functions, since they are not stomping on each others variables. If you need these temporary arrays initialized and declared the same way and you want to avoid repetition, you could just make a struct containing them, using default member initializers.

Comment: @Sam_Varshavchik I think I may be coming off as knowing more than I do. This is my fist attempt as using classes and creating a custom library. I have looked at multiple tutorials in order to create what I have here. Can you go into a little detail on what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you were having with declaring these variables in the `.h` or `.cpp` is that in both cases it makes variables global (unless you were declaring them as member variables). Making the variables global like that could indeed cause havoc.

I would try to solve this by reconsidering your class interface. I think that `Info_Saver` should not worry about the CSV file path or extension, as this creates issues:

1. User is not aware that you are requiring a CSV file, because this is not apparent from the `char * File_Name` parameter.
2. Appending an absolute path and `.csv` to the `File_Name` is completely invisible to the users of this class, as it is an implementation detail. `Info_Saver` should not have this responsibility ([First of the SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).
3. Dangerously trivial stack-based overflow with filenames larger than 33 characters (`/` + `.csv` + `/` and null byte require 7 characters). Your `char Temp_File[40]` only has so much space.

Thus, you could instead consider the following interface:

```
class Info_Saver {
    #define FORMAT_FFAT true
    public:
        void Save_Info(const char * Csv_File_Path, int Value_In);

        void Format_Space();

        void Delete_Parameter(const char * Csv_File_Path);

        void Read_Parameter(const char * Csv_File_Path, char * Value_Out);

        void List_Dir(const char * Dir_Name, uint8_t levels);
};
```

With these interface changes, the duplicate parameter modifications can now be removed from the implementations:

```
char Temp_File[40] ="/";
char End_File[8] = ".csv";

strcat(Temp_File, File_Name);
strcat(Temp_File, End_File);
```

This brings several benefits:

1. User now knows to provide a valid path to a CSV file.
2. Adding absolute path and `.csv` are now implementation details of the user. If this is common, you can implement it as a separate function somewhere where the users of this class can use it.
3. `Info_Saver` no longer needs to worry about how large the provided file path is.

Furthermore, there are some other design decisions you could think about:

- Consider whether or not `List_Dir` belongs to `Info_Saver`. This seems more like a generic folder listing utility than something related to `Info_Saver`.
- You could have each `Info_Saver` object only work on a single CSV file reducing the duplicate parameters. Otherwise, there is little to no need for the class, as you could implement the methods as free functions instead.

For example, with this design each of the methods act on the `m_Csv_File_Path`:

```
class Info_Saver {
    #define FORMAT_FFAT true
    public:
        // Needs implementation
        Info_Saver(const char * Csv_File_Path);

        void Save_Info(int Value_In);
        void Format_Space();

        void Delete_Parameter();
        void Read_Parameter(char * Value_Out);
        
        // Move this somewhere else?
        void List_Dir(const char * Dir_Name, uint8_t levels);
    private:
        const char * m_Csv_File_Path;
};
```

If member variables (`m_Csv_File_Path`) and their behavior are still unknown to you, the design described earlier is a fair compromise. This approach requires a bit more work at the call sites, as you now need to take care that each CSV file uses their own `Info_Saver` object. You also have to take care that the lifetime of `m_Csv_File_Path` does not exceed the caller's `Csv_File_Path` lifetime.

Comment: I was using const char initially, but some issue cause me to change to char. The issue could have easily been cause by my lack of understanding between the two.

Comment: The first example will most likely cause issues because of how the main program works and how I plan to utilize this library. I have several hundred variables and I am attempting to not create more by reusing others. There are about 20 variables that will be handed to this library and it will then store information related to those variables. I will give this a shot and make some mods as I go. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: @WhiskE I get what you mean. As a more intermediate solution, I guess you could try refactoring the `char[]` and `strcat` stuff to a separate `static` function in `Info_Saver.cpp`. Eg. either `static char* Get_Path(const char * File_Name)` that uses dynamic allocation, or even `static char* Get_Path(const char * File_Name, char* Out_Path, size_t Out_Size)` that would use the caller's local array.